# Transferring a Pointer From C++ To Python Compatible with Host and Device Memory

Tags: c++, cuda, ctypes, python-c-api, cupy

I have a Python function (named `apply_filter`), whose execution may involve either the CPU (using `NumPy`) and GPU (using `CuPy`). The function takes an input-buffer object, represting a pointer to data either in system memory or on the GPU's global device memory.

I want to invoke this from a C++ code using the Python C API. In order to do so, I need to supply the function, on the C++ side with something to pass as the input-buffer object - which in my case will correspond to a raw pointer. But I'm not sure how to do this.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

**The invoking code, in C++**:

```
#include <Python.h>

void PythonObjectWrapper::applyFilter(float* image, std::array<int, 3> dim) {
    PyObject* python_method = PyObject_GetAttrString(class_object_, method_name_);
    PyObject* py_image = ??? // convert C-array to PyObject
    PyObject* method_args = PyTuple_New(2);
    PyTuple_SetItem(method_args, 0, py_image);
    PyTuple_SetItem(method_args, 1, ...); // transfer dim
    PyObject* py_filtered_image = PyObject_CallObject(python_method, method_args);
    float* filtered_image = ??? // convert PyObject to C-array
}
```

**The invoked function, in Python:**

```
class Filter:
    def __init__(self, gpu):
        self.gpu_ = gpu

    def apply_filter(self, image_ptr, dim)
        image_array = ??? // convert image_ptr PyObject to NumPy / CuPy array
        apply_filter_(image_array)
        filtered_image_ptr = ??? // convert image_array to ptr
        return filtered_image_ptr
```

How do I complete the 4 lines marked with `???`?

---

Bonus points for a solution avoiding any unnecessary copies (especially from Host to Device in some direction) and do everything efficiently and will support both run modes (CPU/GPU) in a robust manner.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>This solution may not be optimal or the most efficient, but it does work:</sub>

There is a delicate way to handle each of the 4 `???` signs you spread out your code. Let's go over them in order -

**Convert C-ptr to PyObject on Host**

A convenient way to do so is to use `PyByteArray`:

```
PyByteArray_FromStringAndSize(
    reinterpret_cast<char *>(image),
    sizeof(float) * dim[0] * dim[1] * dim[2]);
```

**Convert C-ptr to PyObject on Device**

In this case, `PyByteArray` won't deliver the goods, since it is only suitable for continuous memory on the Host. A convenient way to wrap a raw pointer as a `PyObject` is `PyCapsule`, which can be initialized as follows -

```
PyCapsule_New(reinterpret_cast<void *>(image), "image", NULL);
```

Note that the destructor is not needed here (sends NULL) since the C-code is in charge of this allocated device memory.

**Convert PyObject to Numpy Array**

The `PyByteArray` points to contiguous memory on the Host, and can thus be read as a simple buffer by `NumPy` using -

```
image_buffer = np.frombuffer(
    image_ptr,
    dtype=np.float32,
    count=dims[0] * dims[1] * dims[2])
image_array = np
    .asarray(image_buffer, type=np.float32)
    .reshape(dims[2], dims[1], dims[0])
    .transpose(1, 2, 0)
```

The reshape and transpose operations are needed in order to convert the array shape from C-order (as used by C++) to Fortran-order (as used by Numpy).

**Convert PyObject to CuPy Array**

So that's probably the most tricky one. You need to use the Python C-API directly (using `ctypes.pythonapi`) in order to unpack the pointer, and then some `CuPy` utilities to transform it into an array. The `PyCapsulte_GetPointer` method is not compatible with the exact way our `PyCapsule` was created (I still do not completely understand why), and thus requires manual re-definition of the expected `restype` and `argtypes`.

First, we need to open the `PyCapsule` obtaining the raw pointer on the device -

```
ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_GetPointer.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_GetPointer.argtypes = 
    [ctypes.py_object, ctypes.c_void_p]
raw_address = ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_GetPointer(
    image_ptr, self.pycapsule_name_.encode('utf-8'))
raw_ptr = ct.c_void_p(raw_address)
```

Now, we need to define the `CuPy` array based on this `raw_ptr` with the appropriate size -

```
mem = cp.cuda.MemoryPointer(
    cp.cuda.UnownedMemory(
        raw_ptr.value,
        dims[0] * dims[1] * dims[2] * cp.dtype(cp.float32).itemsize,
        None),
    0)
cupy_array = cp.ndarray(dims, dtype=cp.float32, memptr=mem)
cupy_array = cp
    .asarray(cupy_array, dtype=cp.float32)
    .reshape(dims[2], dims[1], dims[0])
image_array = cp.transpose(cupy_array, axes=(1, 2, 0))
```

And that's it (for the input...)! Now you can robustly write your code (using either `np` or `cp` prefix using an appropriate wrapper) to work on both CPU and GPU.

---

Oh, you also want to return this array as a raw pointer back to `C++`? This raises some more complications:

**Convert NumPy Array to PyObject**

That's easy, simply

```
filtered_image_ptr = image_array.copy(order='C').data
```

**Convert CuPy Array to PyOjbect**

Here you need to again wrap your raw pointer as a `PyCapsule`. Again you need to redefine the `restype` and `argtypes` of the Python C-API methods.

```
 ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_New.restype = ctypes.py_object
 PyCapsule_Destructor = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.py_object)
 ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_New.argtypes = 
    [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_char_p, PyCapsule_Destructor]

 image_raw_ptr = ctypes.c_void_p(image_array.data.ptr)
 name = ctypes.c_char_p(f"b'{self.pycapsule_name_}'")
 filtered_image_ptr = ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_New(image_raw_ptr, name, PyCapsule_Destructor(0))
```

**Convert PyObject to C-ptr on Host**

You can unpack the value returned from the `NumPy` array as a `Py_buffer`.

```
Py_buffer buffer;
PyObject_GetBuffer(py_filtered_image, &buffer, PyBUF_FORMAT);
memcpy(
    filtered_image,
    buffer.buf, dim[0] * dim[1] * dim[2] * sizeof(float));
```

**Convert PyObject to C-ptr on Device**

Simply unpack the `PyCapsule`. Here for some reason there's no need for redefinition of `restype` and `argtypes`.

```
auto* filtered_image_ptr = reinterpret_cast<float*>(
    PyCapsule_GetPointer(py_filtered_image, "slices"));
cudaMemcpy(
    filtered_image, 
    filtered_image_ptr, dim_.Volume() * sizeof(float), 
    cudaMemcpyHostToHost);
```

Comment: Try and fit your code to the answer width, even if it means breaking lines.